# Why unable to access a service if setting externalTrafficPolicy to Local in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: ip, client, kubernetes

I'm following [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/) guide to apply the source ip feature to my kubernetes cluster.

Firstly, I created a pod by running:

`$ kubectl run source-ip-app --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4`

Then expose it as a NodePort service:

`kubectl expose deployment source-ip-app --name=nodeport --port=80 --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort`

At this point, I'm able to access the service from outside of the cluster and get correct client_address:

> $ curl  10.74.68.49:16860 | grep client
>     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   100   296    0   296    0     0  43167      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 49333
>   client_address=10.168.193.130

But if applying the source ip feature:

`kubectl patch svc nodeport -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'`

I'll get timeout:

> $ curl  10.74.68.49:16860 | grep client
>     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:14 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.74.68.49 port 16860: Operation timed out

I'm wondering what's the reason behind this and how to resolve it.

My env info:

> $ kubectl version
>   Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.3", GitCommit:"2c2fe6e8278a5db2d15a013987b53968c743f2a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-03T07:00:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
>   Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.3", GitCommit:"2c2fe6e8278a5db2d15a013987b53968c743f2a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-03T06:43:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Update:

My cluster has 2 nodes, I get the timeout issue no matter which node ip is accessed.

Comment: tutorial docs say that packets will be dropped and not forwarded if there is no local endpoint for the service. Can you post output of `kubectl get ep nodeport -o json | grep nodeName`

Comment: @stacksonstacks, thanks for the comment. The endpoints got are: "nodeName": "10.74.68.48", "nodeName": "10.74.68.49". The cluster is deployed with --hostname-override=${ip}.  According to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48437), the kube-proxy can't find local endpoints due to the rename. I'm trying to figure out how to avoid this. Because in my prod env, the hostname is overridden.

Comment: That thread says the setting `--hostname-override=${ip}` on each kube-proxy should fix the issue. Have you done that and restarted the kube-proxy pods?

Comment: I'm attempting to do it, as my kube-proxy is a DaemonSet, I'm investigating how to pass --hostname-override to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create kube-proxy.yaml

`kubectl get ds -n kube-system kube-proxy -o yaml > kube-proxy.yaml`

### Edit `kube-proxy.yaml` to include the `HOST_IP` argument

```
# ...
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - ./hyperkube
    - proxy
    - --cluster-cidr=10.2.0.0/16
    - --hostname-override=$(HOST_IP)
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubeconfig
    - --proxy-mode=iptables
    env:
    - name: HOST_IP
      valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
    #...
```

### Update the pods:

`kubectl apply -f kube-proxy.yaml`

This will apply the fix mentioned in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48437, resolving the dropped packets issue.