# No response when "externalTrafficPolicy" is set to "Local"

Tags: kubernetes

I cannot reach the following Kubernetes service when `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` is set. I access it directly through the NodePort but always get a timeout.

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "echo",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/echo",
    "uid": "c1b66aca-cc53-11e8-9062-d43d7ee2fdff",
    "resourceVersion": "5190074",
    "creationTimestamp": "2018-10-10T06:14:33Z",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "echo"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "tcp-8080-8080-74xhz",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 8080,
        "targetPort": 3333,
        "nodePort": 30275
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "k8s-app": "echo"
    },
    "clusterIP": "10.101.223.0",
    "type": "NodePort",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalTrafficPolicy": "Local"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
}
```

I know that for this pods of the service need to be available on a node because traffic is not routed to other nodes. I checked this.

Comment: Does it work as expected when `externalTrafficPolicy` is `Cluster`?

Comment: Yes, it works. Just the source IP is wrong (as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you are connecting from and what command you are typing to test connectivity or what's your environment like.  But this is most likely due to [this known issue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#services-with-externaltrafficpolicy-local-are-not-reachable) where the node ports are not reachable with `externalTrafficPolicy` set to `Local` if the `kube-proxy` cannot find the IP address for the node where it's running on.

This [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/857) sheds more light into the problem. Apparently `--hostname-override` on the kube-proxy is not working as of K8s 1.10. You have to specify the `HostnameOverride` option in the kube-proxy ConfigMap.  There's also a fix described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/69340) that will make it upstream at some point in the future from this writing.

Comment: It is true that we used `--hostname-override` for one of our nodes, but I cannot any log entries like the one given as example in the linked article. I also tried to apply the patch without any success.

Comment: Added more details

Comment: Thanks! What I did to fix this: Remove `--config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf` from the kube-proxy daemon set. Apply the patch at `https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#services-with-externaltrafficpolicy-local-are-not-reachable` with `$(NODE_NAME)` instead of `${NODE_NAME}`.

Comment: This link :- https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#services-with-externaltrafficpolicy-local-are-not-reachable is not containing desired result. pleasse can someone update the anwer with patch

Answer (score 0):

As Jagrut said, the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#services-with-externaltrafficpolicy-local-are-not-reachable) shared in Rico's answer does not contain the desired section with the patch anymore, so I'll share a different thread where stacksonstacks' answer worked for me: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345327/why-unable-to-access-a-service-if-setting-externaltrafficpolicy-to-local-in-a-ku) . This solution consists in editing `kube-proxy.yaml` to include the `HOST_IP` argument.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, request to `node cluster/public ip` which own deployment/pod.

```yaml
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.9x.x.x      <-- request this ip
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.9x.x.x
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

or

```
NAME          STATUS  ...  EXTERNAL-IP
master-node   Ready        3.2x.x.x
worker-node   Ready        13.1x.x.x    <-- request this ip
```

additionally, alway to request same node's ip, use `nodeSelector` in Deployment.