# Can't access kubernetes service which have externalTrafficPolicy as "Local"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm following [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-nodeport) guide to preserve source ip for service type nodeport.

> kubectl create deployment source-ip-app --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4

> kubectl expose deployment source-ip-app --name=clusterip --port=80 --target-port=8080

At this point my service is accessible externally with nodeip:nodeport

When I change the service traffic policy,

> kubectl patch svc nodeport -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'

my service is not accessible.

I found a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345327/why-unable-to-access-a-service-if-setting-externaltrafficpolicy-to-local-in-a-ku)  , But the solution is not much helpful or not understandable for me . I saw some github threads which says its something to do with hostname override in kube proxy , I'm not clear with it too.

I'm using kubernetes version v1.15.3. Kube proxy is running in iptables mode. I have a single master node and few worker nodes.
I'm facing the same issue in my minikube too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-nodeport)

> If there are no local endpoints, packets sent to the node are dropped

So you need to use the correct node IP of the kubernetes node to access the service. Here correct node IP is the node's IP where the pod is scheduled.

This is not necessary if you can make sure every node(master and workers) has a replica of the pod.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm able to access the service with the pod running node ip. However I'm getting client ip as some internal node ip "10.36.0.0", not my client ip. Any idea about it ?

Comment: You said service is not accessible..I thought that was the problem. Please edit your qustion

Comment: After you've mentioned about the endpoints only , I tried with pod node ip and it worked . And resulted into new issue, that I mentioned in  above comment.

Comment: `This is not necessary if you can make sure every node has a replica of the pod`

The pod is now available in all worker nodes, still I can't access it with NodeIP of master. Does the pod needes to be available in master as well ?

Comment: Yes pod need to be available on a node whose IP you use to access it..be it master or worker. For the new issue I suggest to ask a new question

Comment: Thanks for your support . Will raise it as a new issue .